# laravel Route::is not working

Tags: laravel, menu, routes

I have a dynamic menu that I am trying to get to work. When clicking on a menu sub-item, the main menu item should remain open.

This is what works in the theme

```
<li class="nav-item start active open">
```

I have been trying to use

```
<li  class="nav-item  {{ Route::is('*.equip.*') ? 'active open' : null }}">
```

but it is not working. How can one troubleshoot what the problem is? Below is how it is used in the coding.

```
<li class="nav-item {{ Route::is('*.equip.*') ? 'active open' : null }}">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
        <span class="title">Equipment</span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ url('') }}/equip/check_out" class="nav-link">
                <span class="title">Check Out</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ url('') }}/equip/check_in" class="nav-link">
                <span class="title">Check In</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ url('') }}/equip/my_list" class="nav-link">
                <span class="title">What I Have Now</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: quick sanity check: your "working" example has a `start` css class, but your code example does not include this css class. Should it? Assuming that doesn't matter at all, what is the url being checked?

Comment: Thanks for the "sanity check" - but - that was not the problem. The URL reference looks like: http://<doman_name>/public/customer/add  (as an example). Is "Route::is" the correct function to use in this case?

Comment: What is the output of `dd(Route::currentRouteName(), Route::is('*.equip.*'));`?

Comment: Just saw your updated comment. `Route::is()` will compare against the name of the route. `Request::is()` will compare against the actual url. Given your comparison string (`*.equip.*`), I'm assuming you are trying to match on route name, so `Route::is()` would be appropriate.

Comment: @patricus - how would I put this into the code? Is there some kind of "echo" one can run? I tried class="TESTME  {{ dd(Route::currentRouteName(), Route::is('*.equip.*')) }} "  and this resulted in a syntax error (the page would not come up)

Comment: Since it is just a quick debug, just use plain php tags in your view. `<?php dd(...); ?>`

Comment: I had to search for a safe place to put it so that it would not stop the processing. But basically, the values that seem to come back are "null" and "false". Where should a command normally go?

Comment: If `Route::currentRouteName()` is coming back `null`, that means the route you are on is not named. Can you show your route definition?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is `Request::is();` instead of `Route::is()`